# How to sum a column dependent on a value in another column in R

Tags: r

I am wanting to "sum the Length column when mat_Source column = ark" and be able to do this for each of the values in the mat_source column to understand what lengths come from each source.

[image: Data Set]

I have looked at other questions asked on the internet relating to summing data and they are similar but not exactly what i'm after.

Comment: Hi Natalie Storm, welcome to SO. Please do not add data as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, use `dput()` and copy the result into a codeblock in your question. To do that, run something like `dput(head(df), 16)` on your data where df is the name of your data. The output should look like the example in my answer. Also include the code that you have tried so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` package. Note you will need to install `dplyr` prior to running this code:

```
library(dplyr)

# Your data
df <- structure(list(asset_ID = 1:16, length = c(500L, 170L, 480L, 
284L, 30L, 500L, 270L, 476L, 395L, 80L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 110L, 
500L, 363L), age = c(6, 6, 9, 10, 4, 3.09589, 6.79726, 3, 5, 
18.90411, 14, 6, 22, 2, 14, 2), mat_source = c("ark", "bg", 
"brnl", "brnl", "bg", "brnl", "brnl", "ark", "brnl", "ark", "brnl", 
"ark", "ark", "brnl", "brnl", "brnl"), con_num = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

# Result
result <- df %>%
  group_by(mat_source) %>%
  summarise(sum_length = sum(length))

result
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  mat_source sum_length
  <chr>           <int>
1 ark              2056
2 bg                200
3 brnl             3402
```

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand, you can do it by filtering data to ark

```
ark_data <- data[data$mat_source == "ark", ]

ark_total_length <- sum(ark_data$Length)

print(ark_total_length)
```